# Select Control Set Initial Value

Tags: c#, .net, blazor

We know that with `InputSelect` we cannot use both @bind-value and @onchange...

But if we use the latter (with `select` instead `InputSelect`), how can we set a initial value different from the first ? (eg. in this sample set to 2018, the value of a variable)

Something like `if (i == month) => selected`

```
<select @onchange="ChangeYear">
    @for (int i = 2015; i < DateTime.Now.Year + 1; i++)
    {
        <option value="@i">@i</option>
    }
</select>

@code {

    int year = 2018;

    void ChangeYear(ChangeEventArgs e)
    {
        int year = Convert.ToInt32(e.Value.ToString());

        //...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can implement it in a variety of ways, as for instance, define a local variable SelectedYear that is bound to the value property of the select element, and a change event that update the SelectedYear. This actually creates a two-way data binding.

Note that SelectedYear is assigned a default value 2018

```
<select value="@SelectedYear" @onchange="ChangeYear">
    @for (int i = 2015; i < DateTime.Now.Year + 1; i++)
    {
        <option value="@i">@i</option>
    }
</select>

<p>@SelectedYear</p>

@code
 {
    private int SelectedYear { get; set; } = 2018;

    void ChangeYear(ChangeEventArgs e)
    {
        SelectedYear = Convert.ToInt32(e.Value.ToString());

    }
}
```

> We know that with InputSelect we cannot use both @bind-value and
>   @onchange

This is because the compiler add the change event handler to update the Value (Note that it is @bind-Value, not @bind-value)  property of the InputSelect component to the newly selected value. This is why you could have done something like this:

```
<p>@SelectedYear</p>

<EditForm Model="@employees">
    <DataAnnotationsValidator />
     <div>   
        <InputSelect @bind-Value="SelectedYear" Id="SelectedYear" Class="form-control">
            @for (int i = 2015; i < DateTime.Now.Year + 1; i++)
            {
                <option value="@i">@i</option>
            }
        </InputSelect>


    </div>
    <button type="submit">Ok</button>

</EditForm>

@code
 {
    private string SelectedYear { get; set; } = "2018";

    public List<Employee> employees = new List<Employee>();


    public class Employee
    {
        public int YearBorn { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks to point me to value="" attribute of select
I had the doubt to do so, but I was misguided by the Intellisense of VS2019 that doesn't propose...

I knew with InputSelect is easier, but sometimes in the ChangeEvent I have to do some other stuff (enabling/disabling UI pieces, reload data, etc.)

Comment: For anyone else who finds this, note that when using `InputSelect`, the default that you have in the `@bind-Value` variable only works if it's the `value` of the `option` in the `Select`.  It will definitively not work if you try setting it to the `text` or `display` for that `option`, and you may spend far too much time wondering why the default doesn't work!  (And you don't get any errors anywhere indicating you tried to set it to a `value` that isn't value!)

Comment: it works, but is "value" actually a valid select attribute?

Comment: How would you pass the default selection as a parameter instead of as a string constant?

Answer (score 10):

In HTML 'selected' is an attribute of the option. Blazor lets you toggle that with a boolean:

```
<option value="@i" selected="@(i==year)">@i</option>
```

The rest of your code can stay as-is.

Comment: Damn...I knew it should be simple... I was searching a way to write selected (the old html mode) and not selected="true"
Very elegant, thanks

Comment: unfortunately, this won't work in this case as the select is bound with @bind

Answer (score 0):

This Approach worked for me:

```
 <select @bind="selectedValue">
 @foreach (string item in selectionList)
 {
     <option>@item</option>
 }
 </select>
@code {
public string selectedValue {
get { return "defaultValue"; }
set { yourMethod(value); } }
void yourMethod(string value){
  }
}
```

This will ensure binding and trigring the desired action.